# Serialization is not working with serializable interface

Tags: php, debugging, serialization

```
 class foo implements serializable
    {
    public function serialize() {

            return serialize($this);
        }

        public function unserialize($serialized)
        {
            //Revive connection
            AbstractContent::$connection=  DatabaseHandle::getConnection();
            return unserialize($serialized);
        }
    }     


var_dump($this->object); //$this object is instance of class foo returns the exact dump of objects with correc property

     var_dump(unserialize(serialize($this->object))); //Does not dump correctly. only default property values are evaluated, constructor assigned values are ignored, computed values are ignored
```

Comment: Does the object serialize? Or maybe the problem is in unserializating?

Comment: @volitcus it does not thro any errors. and `var_dump(unserialize(serialize($this->object)))` returns the object but with only with default property values (as written in comments in OP)

Comment: But what does `var_dump(serialize($this->object));` return?

Comment: @Voitcus string 'C:8:"foo":4:{r:1;}' (length=23)

Comment: May I also ask what "default values" you mean? The class provided in the code has no properties, and you use `$this` outside of class. This string you answered has also no fields but `r` (I think it is reference to object #1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php):

> When the data is unserialized the class is known and the appropriate
>   unserialize() method is called as a constructor instead of calling
>   __construct(). If you need to execute the standard constructor you may do so in the method

Also, as you're not doing any logic when using `serialize()` you can get away with simply overriding the [_seelp() and __wakeup() magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) instead of implementing `serializable`. Something like:

```
class foo
{
    public function __wakeup() {
        // Do your logic here
    }
}
$foo = new foo();
var_dump(unserialize(serialize($foo)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo implements serilizable
```

should be:

```
class foo implements serializable
```

just a simple spelling error

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. actual code is ok. updated the question. problem still remains.

Comment: i would take it out of a class and just use the built in serialize functions

Comment: without serializable interface if i do serialize directly, i ma getting this error `Fatal error: Couldn't find implementation for method bar::serialize in Unknown on line 0`

a object of bar class is property of class foo. somehow it is not serializing nested object.